# Zend Framework: How to give specific order to javascript files and scripts

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have following javascript files included in layout:

```
$this->InlineScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl('resource/js/jquery.js'));
$this->InlineScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl('resource/js/main/login.js'));
$this->InlineScript()->offsetSetFile(3,$this->baseUrl('resource/js/core.js'));
```

I have following script in view file:

```
<?php $this->InlineScript()->captureStart() ?>
    alert('This is Inline Script in View');
<?php $this->InlineScript()->captureEnd() ?>
```

Right now, my script in view file, is inserting before all javascript files.

How can I insert my inline script  before 'core.js' and after 'login.js' file

Comment: Your second code snippet looks like a placeholder. Right now I am a little stumped about your appendFile methods to the placeholder. I wasn't aware you can do that, but then have you tried prependFile()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in layout you can used appendFile() and prependFile() combinations,if you will have some place for file...

and...

**in "layout.phtml":**

```
<?php echo $this->inlineScript(); ?>
```

**in "test.phtml":**

```
<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureStart() ?>
alert('This is Inline Script in View');
<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureEnd() ?>
```

**result:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--
alert('This is Inline Script in View');
//-->
</script>  
</head>
```